# WordPress Softaculous installing shows Index Of/ directory instead of site

Tags: php, wordpress

After installing WordPress through softaculous (from my cpanel) and going to the directory I just see an indexed list instead of the theme.

[reidsherman.com/wp](https://reidsherman.com/wp)

Similar questions to this hint at a missing index.php, but as you can see there is an index file. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe a misconfiguration of your webserver. If you are using an Apache try this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

in httpd.conf

Comment: Can you help me find the httpd.conf file? I am pretty sure that I'm running apache, but that file is nowhere to be found (I do not have a /etc/ folder).

Comment: If u got a managed webspace this configuration might be done via .htaccess or an special php.ini in your web-root. Check out the FAQ of your hosting service

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my .htaccess file had an alternate default index page, index.html. The fix was to simply comment out that line.